# I need to know if session access to session cookie to read the id each time

Tags: asp.net, session, cookies

I' need to store some not sensible state data eg. language and layout preferences.

I need to know if session is faster then cookie.

Does the session read the session id cookie each time in order to retrieve the correct user session?

Answer (score 0):

Storing the data in cookie has its own advantage

1) Server resource is costly affair , Session is stored on the Server memory so more the session you use , web application may get the penalty. On other hand Cookies are stored on the client machine.

2) If you are planning to store the preference for the user for very long time , cookies will be good option with very long expiry date. The Session will need to be created everytime users login to your website. It means if user do not change the preference frequently store in cookie and if cookie does not exits pull from the database and add it again.

3) Cookies can be read from the client side also. So in case of AJAX kind of work storing the data in cookie will be better.

I do not see Session or cookie will be have large marign on performance , but using server resource like session may make your website slower with large user base.